# Best practice to send auth token from one website to another?

Tags: javascript

I have one website, where a user will login to his/her account, they will then be redirected to another website where they should be logged in automatically. Both website have access to the same database. A user will get authenticated with a token, but how do I pass that along to the other website.

Comment: Send it though the header

Comment: Website A is a php based website, and website B is JavaScript based. How do I then access that token on website B, or is there a way to pass that token along with JavaScript?

Comment: They both have access to the same backend ?

Comment: Yes, they both do.

Comment: When connection to Website A, backend sends a token. Store this token in the cookies. Landing on website B will send this token to backend. Backend will verify this token and allow automatic connection if it is a correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the server technology there are various choices.

You don't tell what platform (windows, linux) is your server on and what web server (Apache, IIS) you use, which web technology you use (ASP.NET, PHP, Ruby, node.js) or framework you use (laravel, symfony, wordpress, ruby on rails). So it's pretty difficult to be precise.

Anyways.

For example on IIS you can choose to store session state in these ways:

- **InProc** mode, which stores session state in memory on the Web server. This is the default.
- **SQLServer** mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.
- more...

For Apache/PHP running on Linux you can rsync the session folder across machines, or store the session state on the database.

As a last resort you can have a protected websocket that connects the web servers and allows both to query the other about session tokens.

> what should be clear is that the session ID available to the client (cookie, local storage or whatever) is NOT the session state used by the webserver. Those are two different things.

What you want is called **SSO** (Single Sign-On).

To be clear: you have to **move information directly between the servers** without the aid of the client. This is important for security reasons and should not be confused with the session ID available to the client.

Furthermore, there's the problem of cross-domain. This only applies if the domains (URLs) of the two servers are different. For security reasons you cannot send cookies of one domain to the other. Or access the local storage of another domain from a page that has been loaded on the other. In other words, when you set the session ID in a cookie or local storage under one domain, it won't be accessible on the other domain.

> But there's a way around the domain boundary, shown below.

In your case the database is probably the best option. You can do as follows.

- on login on either side you store the session ID and a timestamp in a SQL table that points to both user's login data (one for the first server, the other for the second -- just in case you use heterogenous web technologies such as ASP.NET and PHP);
- when you redirect the client from one domain (server) to the other, you have to ensure the session ID is passed along (without cookies or local storage) -- you can do that easily by putting the session ID into the query string of the URL, such as this:

  `www.otherdomain.com/landing_page.html?sid=75UFNE784324jEJIRO4234782394JKR`
- on the landing page of the other server you can now take that session ID, query it against the SQL table and retrieve the login information for that server.

I hope this helps you out a bit, it's maybe a bit confusing because it's a generic explanation without concrete code. But with a bit of attention you should be able to do it!